# A bijective mapping from $\mathbb N^k$ to $\mathbb N$?

Tags: combinatorics, inverse

Having $k$ numbers $N_i\in\mathbb{N}$, I'm looking for a bijective mapping

$f:\mathbb{N}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$

So that $f^{-1}\left(N_0\right)=\left(N_1,\ldots,N_k\right)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: May I ask what additional structure should be preserved by isomorphism?

Comment: and what does $N_0$ mean? and what is $(N_1,\cdots,N_k)$?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I suppose $(N_1, \ldots, N_k)$ is a $k$-tuple.

Comment: Do you mean a bijective mapping? (that is, a one-to-one and onto mapping?) When we say "isomorphic mapping" we mean that in addition to bijective-ness, we need to preserve some structure such as $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ or perhaps $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$.

Comment: @EricStucky you're right, I'm looking for a bijective mapping. There's no algebraic structure whatsoever.

Comment: If you are looking for a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$, then here is [mapping $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/444454/26306) that easily extends to any finite $k$ (just use more colors $\ddot\smile$). Of course, composing with itself many mappings $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ is another solution.

Comment: @IttayWeiss dtldarek is correct.

Comment: Please edit the title as well :) And consider revising/deleting the third line, because although it's clear what it means, it's not clear why you are taking the time to mention it specifically.

Comment: @dtldarek : propose it and you will get the score.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov I don't care for score very much, maybe there is some yet marvelous answer which we don't know?

Comment: @dtldarek : your answer will require $k$ colours to be used. I have an additional requirement : only one colour should be used. Is this enough as a structure?

Comment: @dtldarek I didn't notice at first, that you have linked to a question with your proposal, I'm on it now.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov That was an informal statement, you don't have to use any colors at all.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice bijection that works like this (here for $k = 3$):

$$
\color{red}{42},\color{blue}{2013},\color{green}{789},
\to 
\color{blue}{2}\,
\color{red}{0}\,
\color{green}{7}\,
\color{blue}{0}\,
\color{red}{0}\,
\color{green}{8}\,
\color{blue}{1}\,
\color{red}{4}\,
\color{green}{9}\,
\color{blue}{3}\,
\color{red}{2}\,,$$

this is an easy extension of [this $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ bijection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/444454/26306).

Another approach is to use any $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ bijection and compose it with itself, e.g.

$$f_k (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k) = f(a_1, f(a_2, \ldots f(a_{k-1},a_k)\ldots)).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: This is a constructive solution which I could use in a computer program, as I intended to.

Answer (score 1):

To give a bijection $A\leftrightarrow\Bbb N$ amounts to define a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ which includes all elements of $A$.

When $A=\Bbb N^k$ a standard way to do this is to write
$$
\Bbb N^k=\bigcup_{r=0}^\infty A_r,\qquad
A_r=\{(n_1,...,n_k)\in\Bbb N^k\,|\,\sum_{j=1}^kn_j=r\}
$$
and since every $A_r$ is finite we can list all elements of $A_1$, followed by all elements of $A_2$, followed by all elements of $A_3$, and so on.

This certainly works although it may not be easy to say what is the $n$-th $k$-ple ofthe sequence excplicitly.

P.S.: the above is written under the conventional assumption that $0\in\Bbb N$. If, so to speak, $\Bbb N$ starts with 1 the above works in the same way with the observation that the first non-empty subset $A_r$ is $A_k$.