# If $A$ and $B$ are countable sets, show that $A \times B$ is countable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My question is If $A$ and $B$ are countable sets, show that $A \times B$ is countable.

I know the definitions to be a countable set are:

1. A set $A$ is countable if $A$ is finite or countably infinite.
2. A set $A$ is countably infinite if $A \thicksim \mathbb{N}$ ( same cardinality)

I just want to be walked through this problem for studying reasons.

Comment: In resumen, you must show that exists a bijection $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.

Comment: ... and [bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444447/bijection-between-mathbbn-and-mathbbn-times-mathbbn) and many others.

Comment: I hope you're willing to use the axiom of choice.

Comment: @WillO He does not need it: he has just two functions to choose. You need AC to prove that the disjoint union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Comment: @WillO This does not require the Axiom of Choice (or any weaker version stronger than Axiom of Finite Choice).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli and Hayden:  You are right.  My bad.

Comment: See Cantor proof on the carnality of the rational numbers.  Same arguments can be applied.

Comment: @DougM Are you sure you mean **carnality**? :-)

Comment: @Bungo  In all their fleshy, dirty ways.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are countable, then they can be listed $A={a_1, a_2,\ldots}$ and
$B={b_1,b_2,\ldots}$.  Then the map $(a_k,b_n) \rightarrow 2^k3^n$ is an injection from $A\times B$ into $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A= \{a_1,a_2,... \}$ and $B= \{b_1,b_2,... \}$

Let $A_k=\{(a_n,b_k):n \in \Bbb N \}$ and $k=1,2,...$

I think it's clear that $A_k$ are equinumerous to $A$ for all $k=1,2,...$ and therefore countable

This way $A \times B= \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ and we know that a countable union of countable sets is a countable set